# How to implement a composite event after p:calendar value is set?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, event-handling, composite-component

I've a composite component with calendar inside.

I need to catch an event when calendar was changed but in my mainBean (not composite bean)

So, I've got 4 files: mainBean.java, main.xhtml and coposite: myCalendar.xhtml with calComp.java.

I want to call 'changed' event in mainBean.java and have no idea how to achive that.

Here is the code : 
Composite:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute
            name="myListener"
            method-signature="void listener()" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="container">
        <p:calendar
            value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            valueChangeListener="#{cc.valueChanged}"
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  update="@this,:buttonpanel" listener="#{cc.attrs.myListener}"/>
        </p:calendar> 
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

Main page:

```
<cc:inputdate value="#{mainBean.item.myDate}" myListener="#{mainBean.event1}"/>
```

bean for main page:

```
public void event1()
    {
        log("Event1!!!!");
    }
```

I've got also log in setMyDate() method. So I now exactly when mainBean has new date set.

In composite's bean there is only "log code", but It was enough to see that Event1 was called before the new value was set..

My question is: How can I catch an event, that will be called AFTER the value for myDate is set? In that event I want to do "getMyValue" with new value.

Please help

Thanks.